# YouTube video player in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using this package [youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) to display YouTube videos in my flutter application but I have a little of issues that I can't solve yet.

firstly, How can hide the YouTube video name and channel photo, and YouTube logo from my video?

secondly, how can hide YouTube recommendation videos at the end of my video?

finally, is there a way to prevent users to rewatch this video?

this my code

```
YoutubePlayer(
    controller: YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.initialUrl).toString(),
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
            hideThumbnail: true,
            autoPlay: false,
            mute: false, 
        ),
    ),
),
```

my dispose code

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this cause I have the same exact requirements.